# jTextField color problems. Color not displaying in jTable either

Tags: java, jtable

This is part of an "AddEntry" class. The color of the text field only changes in the first text field and not all four.

```
 private class HandlerClass implements ItemListener {
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {

        if (friend.isSelected())
        {
        jTextField1.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        jTextField2.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        jTextField3.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        jTextField4.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        }
```

Once the data has been inputted the user adds it to a jTable.

```
jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
            AddressBookMain.addEntry(new AddressBook(jTextField1.getText(), jTextField2.getText(), jTextField3.getText(), jTextField4.getText()));
        }
    });
```

The driver program adds the contact data to a jTable, but the colors do not show. They go back to black. How do I keep the color changes?

```
`jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
            new AddEntry().setVisible(true);
        }
    });`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text that you get from the JTextFields are just plain vanilla Strings, and strings don't have a color.

You need to create a custom cell renderer for the JTable. You can read about renderers here:
[How to Use Tables in the Swing tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Comment: Would it be better than to move the checkbox/color labeling buttons to the driver program where the JTable is? It doesn't make sense to just change the plain strings, which is what I was afraid I was doing. Thanks again Kaj.

Comment: No, you would still need to create a custom renderer for the table.